# having trouble with a loop

Tags: java

I need to put a loop on this asking if the player would like to play again. If the user says yes restart the game. If they say no end the game. I am having trouble with this all together. Please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW4ChrisMuncher
  {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double a;
    int b;

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    double userNum = input.nextDouble();
    a = userNum;  

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number (no decimals!)");
    int userNum2 = input2.nextInt();
    b = userNum2;        



    double c = min(a, b);
    double d = max(a, b);
    double e = abs(a);
    double f = pow(a, b);     



    System.out.println("The minimum value of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + c );        
    System.out.println("The maximum value of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + d );
    System.out.println("The absolute value of "+ a+ " is " + e );
    System.out.println(+ a + " to the power of " + b + " is " + f );

  }

  // Returns the minimum of two numbers
  public static double min(double n1, int n2) 
  {
    double min;
      if (n1 > n2)
       min = n2;
      else
        min = n1;

      return min; 
   }

   // Return the max between two numbers
   public static double max(double n1, int n2)
   {
     double max;
       if (n1 > n2)
        max = n1;
       else
         max = n2;

       return max;
    }


   //Returns the absolute value of the two numbers
   public static double abs(double n1)
   {
     if (n1 < 0)
       return -n1;
     else 
       return n1;

   }


   public static double pow(double n1, int n2)
   {
     double f = 1;
         for (int i =0; i< n2; i++)
           {
             f = f * n1;
           }
         return f;

   }


 }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i need help putting a loop on this

Comment: A loop on what? You've given no descriptive information as to *what* you're facing issues with. What have you tried? What errors are you receiving? What don't you understand?

Comment: you may want take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: He may be being a little bit ambiguous, but his question made sense to me: "If the user says yes restart the game. If they say no end the game. I am having trouble with this all together." AKA, how do I restart the game.

Comment: Chris, if a response is correct, you should upvote it and mark it as the correct answer so that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy!

Just grab a while loop and do something like this:

```
String s = "yes";
while(s.equals("yes") || s.equals("y")) {
    //whatever you want repeated
    System.out.println("Would you like to repeat?");
    s = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Think about it. If the person enters "yes", then the while loop will still be true, so it'll start from the beginning. Otherwise, if the person enters anything but "yes", the while loop condition will be false, and the loop will be terminated.

I hope that helps. Good luck :)